# Error in UseMethod("train") : no applicable method for 'train' applied to an object of class "formula"

Tags: r

Tried to use `RRegrs()` function on `BostonHousingPrice` data in R, but getting error as shown in the image.

How can I tackle below error in R?

[image: Error in RRegrs()]

Comment: Have you eventually found a solution for the issue? I am having the same problem.